# finding rectangle in number grid with largest corner sum

Tags: algorithm, optimization

Given a rectangular grid with width `width` and height `height`, a *rectangle* is defined by four natural numbers, `left`, `right`, `top`, and `bottom`, satisfying:

- `left < right` and `top < bottom`;
- `left` and `right` in range `[1, width]`;
- `top` and `bottom` in range `[1, height]`.

The *corners* of a rectangle are the positions of the grid at coordinates `(left, top)`, `(right, top)`, `(left, bottom)`, and `(right, bottom)`.

Given a rectangular grid of integers, the *value* of a rectangle is the sum of the numbers in the grid at the corners of the rectangle. Is there an efficient algorithm that, given such a grid, finds a rectangle with the maximum value? If necessary, we may constrain the range of numbers in the grid.

A brute force algorithm is quadratic in the size of the grid, `width * height`, because there are linearly many choices for each pair `(left, top)` and `(right, bottom)`. But I am wondering if this problem can be solved in linear, linearithmic, or similar time.

Comment: The brute force method would actually have factorial runtime complexity. Rectangles are defined as combinations of `(x,y)` tuples, and the number of combinations scales factorially with the size of the input set.

Comment: @ColonelThirtyTwo Not true. There are `width` many choices for `left` and `height` many choices for `top` so there are `width * height` many choices of pairs `(left, top)`. We aren't forming combinations because we aren't taking subsets.

Comment: @DavidEisenstat I would be interested in seeing it even if it isn't optimal.

Comment: The original wording of the question allowed all corners of the rectangle to coincide at a maximum entry of the grid, which is obviously not what I intended, so I edited to require left < right and top < bottom.

Comment: What is exactly the value of the rectangle? `left+right+top+bottom`?

Comment: @Bentoy13 `grid[(left, top)] + grid[(right, top)] + grid[(left, bottom)] + grid[(right, bottom)]`.

Comment: @jef Ok, my bad, I didn't read properly the OP. Thank you for the explanation

Answer (score 2):

Suppose that the grid is m×n with m≤n. Here's a O(m<sup>2</sup> n)-time algorithm. For each pair of rows (m choose 2), compute their element-wise sum and consider the sum of the two greatest entries of the resulting vector.

Comment: It feels like there might be a better algorithm - but I can't think what.  What is your intuition?

Comment: @PeterdeRivaz Yes, this algorithm is still brute-force in the rows. It just uses a more efficient way to extract the 2 largest items of a list than brute force. I was hoping there would be some way to solve this problem with DP or to frame it as another problem that has an efficient solution, but I was unable to think of how.

Comment: @PeterdeRivaz I can't decide whether I think that there should be some approach that uses convolution or whether this should go the same way as the 2D maximum subarray problem.